# In R/rvest, how to get href information ( the linkage following click text)

Tags: r, rvest

In R/rvest, as  below code , I can run the  `html_text()`, but when i run want to get the linkage following every text  `web %>% html_node("div.p13n-desktop-grid") %>%  html_attr(name='href')` failed .Anyone can help? Thanks!

[image]

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Industrial-Scientific-3D-Printers/zgbs/industrial/6066127011/ref=zg_bs_pg_1?_encoding=UTF8&pg=1"
web <- rvest::read_html(url)
web %>% html_node("div.p13n-desktop-grid") %>% html_text() %>% strsplit("#") # ok
web %>% html_node("div.p13n-desktop-grid") %>%  html_attr(name='href') # want to get the linkage following the click text, but failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (shortened) product links and link texts:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Industrial-Scientific-3D-Printers/zgbs/industrial/6066127011/ref=zg_bs_pg_1?_encoding=UTF8&pg=1"
web <- rvest::read_html(url)

# "div.p13n-desktop-grid a[tabindex] + a" : 
# text links are adjacent siblings of image links & image links have tabindex attribute

prod_links <- web %>% html_elements("div.p13n-desktop-grid a[tabindex] + a")
tibble(
  # shorten links, keep only /pb/item_id/ part
  href =  prod_links %>% html_attr(name='href') %>% sub('.*(/dp/\\w*/).*','www.amazon.com\\1', .),
  descr = prod_links %>% html_text2()
)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    href                          descr                                          
#>    <chr>                         <chr>                                          
#>  1 www.amazon.com/dp/B07BR3F9N6/ Official Creality Ender 3 3D Printer Fully Ope…
#>  2 www.amazon.com/dp/B07FFTHMMN/ Official Creality Ender 3 V2 3D Printer Upgrad…
#>  3 www.amazon.com/dp/B09QGTTQKG/ ANYCUBIC Kobra 3D Printer Auto Leveling, FDM 3…
#>  4 www.amazon.com/dp/B07GYRQVYV/ Official Creality Ender 3 Pro 3D Printer with …
#>  5 www.amazon.com/dp/B083GTS8XJ/ ANYCUBIC Wash and Cure Station, Newest Upgrade…
#>  6 www.amazon.com/dp/B09FXYSFBV/ ANYCUBIC Photon Mono 4K 3D Printer, 6.23'' Mon…
#>  7 www.amazon.com/dp/B07J9QGP7S/ ANYCUBIC Mega-S New Upgrade 3D Printer with Hi…
#>  8 www.amazon.com/dp/B07Z9C9T42/ ELEGOO 5PCs FEP Release Film Mars LCD 3D Print…
#>  9 www.amazon.com/dp/B08SPXYND4/ Voxelab Aquila 3D Printer with Full Alloy Fram…
#> 10 www.amazon.com/dp/B07DYL9B2S/ Official Creality Ender 3 S1 3D Printer with D…
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

There are 50 products per page but only first 30 are included in the grid, the rest would be loaded in small chunks as you'd scroll down. Unless descriptions are needed, it's bit easier to just collect all IDs from `data-client-recs-list` and build links from those:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Industrial-Scientific-3D-Printers/zgbs/industrial/6066127011/ref=zg_bs_pg_1?_encoding=UTF8&pg=1"
web <- rvest::read_html(url)
client_recs_list <- web %>% 
  html_element("div.p13n-desktop-grid") %>% 
  html_attr(name='data-client-recs-list') %>% 
  fromJSON(flatten = TRUE) %>% 
  tibble()

client_recs_list %>% 
  select(1,2) %>%
  mutate(prod_link = paste0('www.amazon.com/dp/', id, '/'), .after = id)
#> # A tibble: 50 × 3
#>    id         prod_link                     metadataMap.render.zg.rank
#>    <chr>      <chr>                         <chr>                     
#>  1 B07BR3F9N6 www.amazon.com/dp/B07BR3F9N6/ 1                         
#>  2 B07FFTHMMN www.amazon.com/dp/B07FFTHMMN/ 2                         
#>  3 B09Y54CWXY www.amazon.com/dp/B09Y54CWXY/ 3                         
#>  4 B07GYRQVYV www.amazon.com/dp/B07GYRQVYV/ 4                         
#>  5 B09L81S4L7 www.amazon.com/dp/B09L81S4L7/ 5                         
#>  6 B09JNMRS7R www.amazon.com/dp/B09JNMRS7R/ 6                         
#>  7 B09WHW8YXS www.amazon.com/dp/B09WHW8YXS/ 7                         
#>  8 B09W5CSFZQ www.amazon.com/dp/B09W5CSFZQ/ 8                         
#>  9 B09KXNYJLH www.amazon.com/dp/B09KXNYJLH/ 9                         
#> 10 B09R4QDVY5 www.amazon.com/dp/B09R4QDVY5/ 10                        
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: there are 50 products in this page.  But the code only retrun 30 linkages ? How to handle it ? Thanks!

Comment: Products #31 .. #50 are loaded only when you scroll down. Though list of 50 product IDs is there,  added another block to show how to use those to build Amazon links.

Comment: thanks , this is greate. If i want to scroll donw the page , how to update the code ?

Comment: To clarify, you don't "scoll" with rvest. When you open Amazon Best Sellers page in your browser, links and descriptions for first 30 products are delivered, this is the list you'd get with first provided sample.  As you scroll down in your browser, Javascript dynamically fetches rest of the products in multiple chunks.  You have to monitor network tab in you browser's developer tools to capture those additional calls so you could simulate the same javascript behavior with rvest (or with httr),

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute is an attribute of the `a` tags. Not clear which one you want, there are 119 `href` found:

```
web %>% 
  html_node("div.p13n-desktop-grid") %>% 
  html_elements("a") %>%
  html_attr(name = 'href') 
#   [1] "/Comgrow-Creality-Ender-Aluminum-220x220x250mm/dp/B07BR3F9N6/ref=zg_bs_6066127011_1/132-1194669-0063960?pd_rd_i=B07BR3F9N6&psc=1"                                
#   [2] "/Comgrow-Creality-Ender-Aluminum-220x220x250mm/dp/B07BR3F9N6/ref=zg_bs_6066127011_1/132-1194669-0063960?pd_rd_i=B07BR3F9N6&psc=1"                                
#   [3] "/product-reviews/B07BR3F9N6/ref=zg_bs_6066127011_cr_1/132-1194669-0063960?pd_rd_i=B07BR3F9N6"                                                                    
#   [4] ......
```

Comment: I need the linkage in the red retangular box (refer to post image). Thanks!